# Really clean character sheet?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, character-sheets

Right before 4e came out a friend showed me a 3.5 character sheet that was very clean. The difference between it and pretty much every other character sheet I've been able to find is that it didn't have space for the math, assuming you can work out the numbers on your own. For example it only had what your actual fort, ref and will saves were, not all the numbers you used to get them. This made it much easier to find the values you actually wanted during play.

Does anyone know what character sheet this was, and if a pathfinder version of it, or a similar sheet, exists?

Edit: I have been able to contact the friend that showed me this sheet, and apparently they took it down at the request of WotC (I don't know the story behind this or why they would want a character sheet taken down) so it is unlikely to be found. I am interested in this style of character sheet. I've awarded the answer, but am not a fan of the particular one posted, so would like to see more 'clean, mathless' character sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a sheet on Pathfinder Database that matches your description.  It's 1-page with just boxes for the numbers, not extra ones for the math.  It's not fill-able, meaning you'll have to print it out on your own.

- [Direct download](https://web.archive.org/web/20110510152640/http://www.pathfinderdb.com/component/docman/doc_download/49-one-page-character-sheet)

Comment: It should be noted you have to copy/paste that link, because pathfinder.db checks the HTTP_REFERER and will bump you back to the list of sheets if you just click on the link from here. Sad pandas.

Comment: Unfortunately, the site linked to no longer exists.